# Dealing with complicated ActiveRecord associations

Tags: mysql, ruby, activerecord, associations, hierarchy

I'm attempting to build a fairly complex relationship. As you can tell from the SQL below, I've got three (four if you include User) models here at play. Membership, Group and Role.

Users belong to groups via a Membership, which itself can have a role. So a User has a Role in a Group through the Membership.

What I want to do is ORDER the memberships of a particular group via the Role that the User has in the Membership. Roles have a "rank" associated with it. So, CEO = 3, Department Chair = 2, Manager = 1, Worker = 0 (for example). To complicate matters, a role can be subordinate to another role. So CEO could be part of a role called Board of Directors, and Department Chair and Manager could be part of a role called Upper Management (or something).

As you can see from my SQL below, I've got it working, I just need to figure out how to turn this into an ActiveRecord association so that when I find a group, I can say group.memberships and that should be ordered according to role-rank.

```
SELECT `memberships`.* from `memberships`
 INNER JOIN `groups` ON `groups`.id = `memberships`.group_id
 INNER JOIN `roles` ON `memberships`.role_id = `roles`.id
 INNER JOIN `roles` `role_cat` ON `role_cat`.id = `roles`.type_id

WHERE `groups`.id = "HHC" AND `memberships`.expiration > CURDATE()
ORDER BY `role_cat`.rank DESC, `roles`.rank DESC
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure the query does what you want, here's what I think the most straightforward way to get an AR relation out of it, given that you have a `group` you want to do the query for:

```
group.memberships.joins(:role).
  joins('join roles as roles_cat on role_cat.id=roles.type_id').
  where("groups.id='HHC' and memberships.expiration>curdate()").
  order('role_cat.rank desc, roles.rank desc')
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're dealing with complicated joining queries, I've found it best to create a view that represents a join model.

Once you've done that, you can create that model if there are accessory properties that you need access to, and use `has_many :join_model_name` or if you just need to get right through to one of the joined models, you can use `has_and_belongs_to_many :model_name`

Sure can learn a lot from experience in 6 months :)

Thank you Hargrimm for your help!